Ubuntu rendering issues for applications
I recently reinstalled Ubuntu on my VMware and VirtualBox. I've been noticing that whenever I hover over certain applications, they start to disorder, or even when I'm using Brave browser that certain images won't load and tend to be distorted. These issues have occurred on both virtual machines.

